# Access Union Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am new to access and need some help I have created a Union Query named as FE and want that union query FE to view only 2 columns...Now when I run FE query I see "County, [Total Of VoteCount]" these 2 columns which I coded next to each other along with I can see all columns which I don't want to view in the FE union query. Please help ....
[Output of below code... However, I want only 2 columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71naB.png)

My SQL Code within FE is

```
Select County, [Total Of VoteCount],  * From AGC
UNION ALL 
Select County, [Total Of VoteCount], *From CBC;
```

[FE is the Union Query that I created using AGC and CBC Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHhTp.png)

Comment: Just remove ", *" before "From". This will select all other fields in the tables
`Select County, [Total Of VoteCount] From AGC
UNION ALL 
Select County, [Total Of VoteCount] From CBC;`

Comment: Perfect Thanks @mamadsp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asterisk symbol `*` means all in `SQL` language. So, remove `*` from both of your query before union. Try below.

```
Select County, [Total Of VoteCount] From AGC
UNION ALL 
Select County, [Total Of VoteCount] From CBC;
```